# Kernel of adjoint of Lie algebra

Tags: differential-geometry, lie-algebras, lie-groups

Let $G$ be a Lie group and $\mathfrak{g}$ its Lie algebra.

The adjoint representation of the Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$ is defined as:

$$ \text{ad: } \mathfrak{g} \rightarrow \text{End}(\mathfrak{g}), X \mapsto [X,\cdot] $$

Now, it holds true that

$$ \text{ker ad} = \mathfrak{z}(\mathfrak{g}) = \{X \in \mathfrak{g} : [X,Y] = 0 \quad\forall\; Y \in \mathfrak{g}\}.$$

On the other hand, the definition of the kernel of this homomorphism is (at least in my mind)

$$ \text{ker ad} = \{ X \in \mathfrak{g} : [X,\cdot] = \text{id}, \text{ i.e. } [X,Y] = Y \quad \forall \;Y \in \mathfrak{g} \}, $$

since the group identity in the endomorphism group is the identity-map.

Evidently, the two sets are not the same, but where is my mistake?

Comment: This is a homomorphism of Lie algebras, not groups. The kernel is as a linear map. i.e. the preimage of zero.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As KotelKanim mentionned in the comments, the adjoint homomorphism is a **Lie algebra** homomorphism, and as such, the kernel is the preimage of the zero vector. The second "definition" of the kernel you gave is what you would expect if Lie algebras were groups - which is not the case. So that much is settled.

Let me just point out two facts:

- The fact that the adjoint homomorphism really is a *Lie algebra* homomorphism (and not merely a linear map) is because of the Jacobi identity. In my opinion, this is the strongest motivation for this axiom of a Lie algebra.
- (Here, I assume the Lie algebra is finite-dimensional.) What you have shown is that, any Lie algebra with trivial center admits a faithful representation. However, much more is true. Indeed, Ado's theorem states that **any** Lie algebra over a field of characteristic zero admits a faithful representation. Later, the restriction on the characteristic was removed, and so we get the following (and perhaps surprising) result: **Every Lie algebra admits a faithful representation.** (For more information, see e.g. this [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ado%27s_theorem)).

Comment: Ado's theorem only works for finite dimensional Lie algebras.  I'm not sure about the generalization you mention.

Comment: @JasonDeVito I'm sorry, I was assuming finite dimension. I will add this.

Comment: @JasonDeVito The generalisation to positive characteristic was proven by Iwasawa, see for example Jacobson's *Lie algebras*.

Comment: @Jason: it is still true that every Lie algebra admits a faithful representation (not necessarily finite-dimensional). This is a corollary of Poincaré-Birkhoff-Witt: see http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3031/cayleys-theorem-for-lie-algebras .