# Simple Lie algebra is a matrix algebra?

Tags: abstract-algebra, lie-algebras

**Wedderburn's Theorem.** Let $A$ be a simple finite $k$-algebra. Then $A$ is a matrix algebra over a finite $k$-algebra $K$ which is a skew field. (Here matrix algebra means $A=M_n(K)$ for some $n$.)

**Question** : $so(n)=T_{id}SO(n)$ is a matrix algebra over $K$ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you referring to the [Artin-Wedderburn theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artin%E2%80%93Wedderburn_theorem)? The theorem only applies to *associative* algebras, not Lie algebras.

Comment: There is Ado's theorem in the context of Lie algebras: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3031/cayleys-theorem-for-lie-algebras

Comment: @HeeKwonLee I'm still not sure what you're asking.  Are you asking why $so(n)$ isn't a counterexample?

Comment: Since $so(n) $ is simple, so by Wedderburn's theorem it is a matrix algebra. That is, $ so(n)=M_l (K) $ for some $l $ and $K $. But $so(n)$ is not associative. Hence we can not apply Wedderburn's theorem.

Answer (score 2):

If I am not being mistaken(I remember from reading Antony Knapp's book), I think $so(n)$ is the matrix algebra of $X\in M^{n\times n}$such that
$$X+X^{T}=0$$
and the relationship should be immediate from the defining relation of $SO(n)$:
$$XX^{T}=1$$by playing with infinitestmals.

Comment: Indeed, this is correct: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lie_algebra#Relation_to_Lie_groups